# Listing Models from ASP pages, with Visual Studio and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am creating a very basic Web application in ASP with Visual Studio, I used the default web site then created the 'Employee' Model. This Model can be stored in the Database using:

```
public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

In the Employee namespace. When I created the Controller for this Model the default Create, Read, Update and Delete methods are created. There is also an index page created that is shown when the page is 1st loaded and this page shows every Employee currently in the database. The code for Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<AnotherWebApp.Models.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>All Employee Options</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("View All", "ViewAll")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
        </th>
        <th>
            <b>Options</b>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is display a basic menu on Index.cshtml and link to a ViewAll page containing the table of all Employees. The problem is it says 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' and the page is not displayed. I cannot see why this code works on Index.cshtml but will not work on ViewAll.cshtml, anybody have suggestions?? Here is a link to some tutorials doing this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you show us the code which actually generates the error and indicate on which line the error occurs?  A `NullReferenceException` is pretty easy to debug, just put a breakpoint on that line and when debugging see which object is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear things up this problem was from the EmployeeController.cs where the View associated with the ViewAll page was being returned. When the ViewAll function looked like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewAll()
{
    return View();
}
```

The list of Employees could not be accessed so

```
@model IEnumerable<AnotherWebApp.Models.Employee>
```

was null.The correct version of this function is:

```
    public ActionResult ViewAll()
    {
        return View(db.Employees.ToList());
    }
```

Now the list of all Employees is accessible and can be easily displayed on the ViewAll page.
Hope this is of help to somebody, if anybody has furthur questions please ask!!